# How can i do specialize meta tags for (tags pages) in blogger?

Tags: tags, blogger, meta-tags

I really need to help!

I'v a blogger tech blog, and i customized robots.txt file to don't crawl into the tags of my posts to noindex it.

I want to index some tag pages of my blog, and i want specify a special meta tags (description and h1 title and keywords) for these tags pages because they have a default meta tags of the blog.

May any one help me and describe to me how can i do special meta tags for some tags pages in blogger?

I will be appreciative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the conditional tag I gave below in the head section.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "YOUR-LABEL"'>

//You can add any meta tags here

</b:if>
```

To remove the default description tag in tag pages you can do this

search for this in your theme = `data:view.description`

and change it to;

```
<b:if cond='!data:view.isLabelSearch'>
      <meta expr:content='data:view.description' name='description'/></b:if>
```

If there is any place where you hang out, you can ask again.

Comment: Thank you for your help  and I did it, and specialized 5 labels finally

Comment: You're welcome, you can share any problem about blogger, i am ready to help with all i know

Comment: Much appreciated  my second problem is how to make these labels pages able to crawl  i told you more details below.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the robots.txt content like this, it will definitely work, this way I've done it before;

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Allow: /search/label/mobiles
```

Also, it may not be in the live test right away, when I tried it, google had updated robot.txt 1 day later.

Set robots.txt like this and wait a bit (max 1 day) it will definitely work.

If it doesn't work, there is a second method, open a new question for it and I will answer it for you.

you should not ask different questions in one title